# How to dynamically alter variable names?

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have the following loop:

```
(1..1000).each do |i|
  user1 = User.create(:name => "Bob#{i}")
  ...
end
```

How can I let the variable name `user1` vary dynamically using `i` to get:

```
user1 == Bob1
user2 == Bob2
user3 == Bob3
```

Comment: Why not use an array to store those users?
`users = (1..1000).map{|i| User.create(...)}`

Comment: I need to do more within the loop

Comment: A local variable declared inside a block is not accessible from outside of the block. So, you can just name your variable `user`.

Comment: what would be point if your local vars inside blocks are not gonna make their way out of the block. Their scope is limited.

Comment: @AnnaSm _"I need to do more within the loop"_ – do you have to do more with the user of the loop's current iteration or with multiple users at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but you can use a `Hash` to get a similar result:

```
(1..1000).each_with_object({}) do |i, users|
  users["user#{i}"] = User.create(:name => "Bob#{i}")
end
```

If you need to access the hash outside the block, just assign it to a variable:

```
users = (1..1000).each_with_object({}) { |i, users| users["user#{i}"] = User.create(:name => "Bob#{i}") }
```

And access a specific user (e.g. `user1`) like this:

```
users["user1"]
```

Or you could use only `i` as a key:

```
users = (1..1000).each_with_object({}) { |i, users| users[i] = User.create(:name => "Bob#{i}") }
```

And access a specific user (e.g. `user1`) like this:

```
users[1]
```

Comment: "Prior to Ruby 2.0"? You mean "Since Ruby 2.1"?

Comment: "Prior to Ruby 2.0, you could actually create local vars dynamically using `eval` or `binding.local_variable_set` methods." – This is wrong. a) You cannot create local variables using `Binding#local_variable_set`. You can only set existing ones. b) `Binding#local_variable_set` was added in Ruby 2.1, it is not available prior to Ruby 2.0. c) `eval` *did* leak scope in the past, but that was in Ruby 1.8 and earlier, which *technically* is "prior to Ruby 2.0", but that statement also includes Ruby 1.9, for which it is not true.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for the clarification, i've updated answer (removed that statement) to avoid confusion.